# Publishing Expo vs React Native Apps

Tags: ios, react-native, deployment, expo

I developed an expo app and now I need to publish it to the app store. I want to know do I only have to publish it using expo or can I publish it as if it's a normal React Native app ?

I know it's easier with expo but I just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: As it stands, this question doesn't look like a programming one. If I am wrong, then please add the code that is failing for you by editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to eject from expo with command `expo eject`. It will create bare React Native code with folders like `android` and `ios`.

It's one way journey - I mean after converting it to Rect Native project, you can't revert changes to expo. Workaround is just reset changes :) And you can do this ejection before every app publish.

Long way but - yes, it's possible